# Understanding the Name of an Activity

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a chatbot which is trying to mimic the backchannel example.

Everything is mostly correct, except I'm having trouble understanding how exactly the code below is supposed to work.

```
  botConnection.activity$
    .filter(function (activity) {
      console.log("show me the activity name passed" + activity.name);
      return activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'changeBackground';
    })
    .subscribe(function (activity) {
      changeBackgroundColor(activity.value);
    });
```

I'm assuming I need to name something changeBackground within my bot perhaps? Also shouldn't the activity.type be a 'message' instead of event?

When I do a console.log to show me the activity.name every message I pass is "undefined". Where exactly do I set the name of the Activity so that I can fire the Change Background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `activity` is a generic envelope of which `message` (text and/or attachments sent between the user and the bot) is the most common type. If you wish to have your client and bot exchange information invisibly to the user then you can use the `event` type. By convention they will be ignored by clients such as [Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/).

The way it's written, your example code logs *every* activity sent from the bot to the client. The field `name` applies to activities of type `event` but not `message`, which is why it's showing as `undefined`.

In this example `changeBackground` is the name of a client function that would do something whenever the bot sends an activity of type `event`.

The piece you're missing right now is the (server) bot code which actually sends that event. See Ryan Volum's [backchannel sample bot](https://github.com/ryanvolum/backChannelBot) for an example of this.